# Add content on the Home Page that already has a Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I know it seems like an easy topic, but I was looking for it everywhere and nobody explains how to do it. I got off with theme for my page (an online store). The problem is that on the homepage I can not add a box/text ... I wish I could write a text box at the bottom of the page (not on the footer ... but under featured products) as if it were a new widget ... But when I'm going to customize, it doesn't give me the option to add new content.
[image]
It should be clarified that when I go to the home page ... directly within wordpress ... there is nothing ... it can only be modified with ‘customize’ within the same page. In fact, if I write on Page-> home, this content does not appear on my homepage since I have a theme installed.
[image]
I tried to download some editors like the composer but they don't work for me on the wordpress theme I have.

Thank you very much